# Set size of textarea using REST in Place

Tags: jquery, css, inplace-editing

I'm not understanding how to bind the event mechanism to JQuery in order to set the size of the textarea using REST-in-Place.  Can someone point me in the right direction?

Per the [documentation](https://github.com/janv/rest_in_place), "`ready.rest-in-place` when the form has been built. This event can be used e.g. to change the size of the field or textarea."

So I've got this loading, but it doesn't seem to change the styling:

```
$('.rest-in-place-body').bind('ready.rest-in-place', function(event, json) {
    el = $(this);
    el.style.width = "250px";
    el.style.rows = "10";
});
```

where my attribute to be edited is Model#body

What am I not getting right about this?

UPDATE:
Here is the div that is clicked on.  I'm not able to see the HTML created by jquery as when I look in Firebug to see what has been changed, it deactivates the edit in place and goes back to this.  Maybe there's another way I don't know about?

```
<div id="event-input" class="rest-in-place" data-url="/events/2" data-object="post" data-formtype="textarea" data-attribute="body">Click to Edit...</div>
```

Comment: Include the html (I suspect the generated `textarea` does not have class `rest-in-place-body`)

Comment: I first attempted using the #event-input, then .rest-in-place, and finally dug into the Rest in Place code and found that the text area was given a class of rest-in-place-#{attribute} which is where I came to the conclusion of using .rest-in-place-body.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `textarea` generated by `restinplace` wont have the class name `rest-in-place-body`. Try

```
$('#event-input').bind('ready.rest-in-place', function(event, json) {
  $(this).find('textarea').attr('rows', '10');
}
```

Comment: even with the addition of the apostrophe after 10, this doesn't work.  I did notice that inside div#event-input, when the field is clicked to be edited, a <form></form> tag appears in the source.  Do I need to be doing something like $(this).<child>.attr('rows', '10');

Comment: Perhaps? Try `$(this).find('textarea').attr('rows', '10`);` Also `var self = $(this)` and then inspect the value of self in the debugger

Comment: the code is not getting executed.  debugger doesn't break and an `alert(self)` doesn't alert.

Comment: doh. Yes it did! I had a typo, but finding the textarea was the answer.  If you want to make it an answer, I'll accept it.  Thanks Stephen!